# Flask App with Flask SocketIO: How to create a systemd unit file?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, flask, socket.io, gunicorn

I want to use Flask and Flask SocketIO for realtime Data Visualization. I have set up the Flask App with this [Digital Oceans Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04). Everything works. I want to create a systemd unit file for running flask with flask socketio in the background. I have tried to change the old systemd unit file (digital oceans tutorial) to run Flask with SocketIO but it doesn't work.

**Systemd Unit File**
(/etc/systemd/system/my_app.service):

```
    [Unit]
    Description=Gunicorn instance to serve my_app
    After=network.target

    [Service]
    User=app_user
    Group=www-data
    WorkingDirectory=/home/user/my_app
    Environment="PATH=/home/user/my_app/venv/bin"
    ExecStart=/home/user/my_app/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:my_app.sock -m 007 wsgi:app

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**NGINX Configuration** (/etc/nginx/sites-available/my_app):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_server;
    location / {
         include proxy_params;
         proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/my_app/my_app.sock;
    }
}
```

This works perfectly.

I want to use Flask SocketIO for realtime Data Visualization.

**New NGINX Configuration**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_server;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    }

    location /socket.io {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/socket.io;
    }
}
```

I stopped the the systemd my_app service  and tested the Flask App by typing:

```
(venv) $ gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w 1 --bind 127.0.0.1:5000 wsgi:app
```

And it works.

Unfortunately the changes in the systemd Unit File doesn't work. I have tried:

```
ExecStart=/home/user/my_app/venv/bin/gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w1 --workers 3 --bind 127.0.0.1:5000 wsgi:app

ExecStart=/home/user/my_app/venv/bin/gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w1 --workers 3 --bind unix:my_app.sock -m 007 wsgi:app
```

**Error Message** (NGINX Error log):
"failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream"

Changing User and Group doesn't work either.

I have no idea how to solve this problem. Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

You're need to update your systemd unit file.
Where you start your server, you should use the default route instead of the loopback address when you start your server.

```
 ExecStart=/home/user/my_app/venv/bin/gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w 3 --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app
```